# get a subView inside a ListView's row layout

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to change the drawable resource used in a ImageView inside a ListView's row.
I'm using this:

```
int wantedPosition = 10; // Whatever position you're looking for
int firstPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - listView.getHeaderViewsCount(); // This is the same as child #0
int wantedChild = wantedPosition - firstPosition;
// Say, first visible position is 8, you want position 10, wantedChild will now be 2
// So that means your view is child #2 in the ViewGroup:
if (wantedChild < 0 || wantedChild >= listView.getChildCount()) {
Log.w(TAG, "Unable to get view for desired position, because it's not being displayed on screen.");
return;
}
View wantedView = listView.getChildAt(wantedChild);
```

if I search with `findViewById` inside `wantedView`, I don't find the `ImageView` that I'm looking for.
How can I refer this ImageView to set another drawable resource?

Comment: What adapter are you using for this ListView? This is not how you interact with views inside a list item.

Comment: A custom ArrayAdapter, but There I'm in the Activity. I don't want to access to the row element inside the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

fast way: use `setTag(position)` (or `getItem` or whatever you want to set as a tag) for your `View` in your adapter (`getView` method or relative) and further use `listView.findViewByTag`